# Syntax for patching a DataVerse table in PowerApps

Tags: powerapps, dataverse

The Data Source is not a SharePoint list but a DataVerse table.  How do I update a few rows in a DataVerse table within a ForAll loop? Sounds so trivial BUT I just can't seem to get past it.

This is my code.

ClearCollect(colMyTable, MyTableFromDataVerse);
RenameColumns(colMyTable, "new_id", "newId");

ForAll(colMyTable, Patch(MyTableFromDataVerse, LookUp(MyTableFromDataVerse, ID(??) = newId(??), {Salary: ThisRecord.Salary (??)}));

Please forgive my question marks and the extra brackets. But I just could not get that line right. What is the syntax on that Patch line?  What should be my equation on the 2nd parameter of the Patch function.

Am I always supposed to pick the Primary Key column for my Patch to work on a DataVerse table? In my case my PK I denoted is an ID autoincrement column. What should I consider for a simple Patch Update to work on a DataVerse table.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank You.